# Docker map windows directory to Jenkins container

Tags: docker, mount, containers

I am running docker for windows 10 home edition, everything works fine except when I try to map a directory as volume

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker run -v d:/data:/data alpine ls /data
```

here is the error i see

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /data.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
```

Here is what I actually want to achieve, Run Jenkins and provide home directory from the host system (Windows)

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker  run -v d:/docker-shared-drive:/var/jenkins_home -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins/jenk
ins
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /var/jenkins_home.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```